# Use Lagrange multipliers to maximize $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ subject to $xyz = 1$

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I need to use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum and minimum values of function f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 subject to the constrain function xyz = 1.

This is what I have so far:

Maximize and Minimize f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 +z^2
Subject to: g(x,y,z) = xyz-1

F(x,y,z,λ) = f(x,y,z) + λg(xyz-1)

Fx = 2x + λyz = 0
Fy = 2y + λxz = 0
Fz = 2z + λxy = 0
Fλ = xyz - 1 = 0

Fx = 2x = -λyz  x = -λyz/2
Fy = 2y = -λxz  y = -λxz/2
Fz = 2z = -λxy  z = -λxy/2

Then this is where I am stumped.  If I multiply all of these together I have

-1/8 λ^3 x^2 y^2 z^2 = 1  I am fairly sure I am headed in a wrong directions

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you
Emily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that your constraint is unbounded, and that $x=n$, $y=1/n$, $z=1$ is a solution for all $n$. It follows that the maximum is infinity, by taking $n\rightarrow\infty$.

For the minimum, as a hint, deduce that $2x^2+\lambda=0$, $2y^2+\lambda=0$ and $2z^2+\lambda=0$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Sorry I think that I am even more confused.  :)  I feel like I should know this but I am drawing a blank.  Thank you for your help so far though.

Comment: OK.  I have figured out where you come up with

Comment: OK.  I have figured out where you come up with  your hint for the minimum.  So if I am reading this right 2x^2 = 2y^2 = 2z^2?  so if this is the case x = +/- y?